# How to rewrite this probability formula?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In probability, I know that

$$P(C=1|W=1)=$$  $$\dfrac{P(C=1,W=1)}{P(W=1)}$$

But what if I have variations like:

$$P(C=1|W=1,R=1) and P(C=1,R=1|W=1) and P(C=1 or R=1|W=1) and P(C=1|W=1 or R=1)$$ and,

$$P(C=1 or R=1|W=1 or S=1)?$$

How can I express it without the 'given' symbol `|` like above?

For example is the following right?

$$ P(C=1|W=1,R=1)=$$  $$\dfrac{P(C=1,W=1,R=1)}{P(W=1,R=1)}$$

Thanks

Comment: Yes your example is correct (assuming the denominator is not $0$)

Comment: What about the other variations?

Comment: $P(C=1\text{ or }R=1 \mid W=1\text{ or }S=1) =\dfrac{P((C=1\text{ or }R=1)\text{ and }( W=1\text{ or }S=1))}{P(W=1\text{ or }S=1)}$ and similarly for all the others

Comment: Somewhere in your textbook should be the **general** definition $$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)},$$ which seems to completely answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

These depend on the rules of operation on sets.

For example P(C=1 or R=1|W=1)
= P((C=1 or R=1) and W=1)/P(W=1)

(A or B) and C = (A and C) or (B and C) (distributive law)

So that equals
P((C=1 and W=1) or (R=1 and W=1))/P(W=1)

If there is such a problem on probability, there should be enough assumptions to get the answer, with some help of algebra of sets.